# Ansible: remote_user gets ignored

Tags: ansible

My Ansible playbook fails, $USER and $HOME are not set correctly on the remote server.

I have a user called `lala` on remote-server.

Most tasks get executed as user root, directly via ssh:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_user = root
```

But this tasks should get executed as user `lala` via `ssh`:

```
    - name: migrate
      command: /home/lala/bin/manage.py migrate
      remote_user: lala
```

This fails. The uid of the remote process is from `lala`, but the environment variables like $HOME $USER are still from user `root`.

I would like ansible to connect to user `lala` via ssh directly.

I can see this clearly if I use `-vvvv`:

```
<coffee-and-sugar.club> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv ... -o 'User="root"' ...
```

How to make ansible connect via `ssh lala@remote-server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't use `remote_user`, instead I set the variable `ansible_user` for the task like this:

```
    - name: migrate
      command: /home/lala/bin/manage.py migrate
      vars:
        ansible_user: lala
```